# Test plan structure is varying from JMeter UI(expected) to the API (wrong)

Tags: java, jmeter

My test plan goes like this in UI

```
Test Plan
   Thread Group1
       Sampler 1
          header manager
          result collector
          bean shell post processor   
       Sampler 2
          bean shell pre processor
          header manager
          result collector
          bean shell post processor
   Thread Group2
       Bean shell pre processor
       Throughput 1
          Sampler 3
              header manager
              result collector
       Throughput 2
          Sampler 4
              bean shell pre processor
              header manager
              result collector
              bean shell post processor  
          Sampler 5
              header manager
              result collector
       Result Collector
```

and in the Java Code i tried adding the samplers like this

```
ThroughputController throughput1 = new ThroughputController();
throughput1.setPercentThroughput(100.0f);

ThroughputController throughput2 = new ThroughputController();
throughput1.setPercentThroughput(0.0f);

TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
testPlan.setSerialized(true);

HashTree throughputTree1 = new HashTree();
HashTree throughputTree2 = new HashTree();

HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();
HashTree threadGroupTree1 = new HashTree();

HashTree samplerTree1 = new HashTree(); 
samplerTree1.add(sampler1,resultCollector1);
samplerTree1.add(sampler1,header1);
```

but the output test plan tree is not as expected.

How can i get the test plan in the same order as i mentioned above like in the UI ?

2.Will the test plan tree vary with Java Versions ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code relying on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) :

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.ThroughputControllerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class JMeterFromCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String jmeterHome = "/tmp/jmeter";

        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler1 = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        sampler1.setName("Sampler 1");
        sampler1.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        sampler1.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler2 = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        sampler2.setName("Sampler 2");
        sampler2.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        sampler2.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler3 = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        sampler3.setName("Sampler 3");
        sampler3.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        sampler3.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        HTTPSamplerProxy sampler4 = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        sampler4.setName("Sampler 4");
        sampler4.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        sampler4.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        ThreadGroup threadGroup1 = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup1.setName("Thread Group 1");
        threadGroup1.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup1.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup1.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup1.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup1.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        ThreadGroup threadGroup2 = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup2.setName("Thread Group 2");
        threadGroup2.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup2.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup2.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup2.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup2.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        ThroughputController throughputController1 = new ThroughputController();
        throughputController1.setName("throughput 1");
        IntegerProperty style = new IntegerProperty();
        style.setName("ThroughputController.style");
        style.setValue(1);
        FloatProperty throughput1 = new FloatProperty();
        throughput1.setValue(100);
        throughputController1.setProperty(throughput1);
        throughputController1.setProperty(style);
        throughputController1.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThroughputController.class.getName());
        throughputController1.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThroughputControllerGui.class.getName());

        ThroughputController throughputController2 = new ThroughputController();
        throughputController2.setName("throughput 2");
        IntegerProperty style2 = new IntegerProperty();
        style2.setName("ThroughputController.style");
        style2.setValue(1);
        FloatProperty throughput2 = new FloatProperty();
        throughput2.setValue(0);
        throughputController2.setProperty(throughput2);
        throughputController2.setProperty(style2);
        throughputController2.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThroughputController.class.getName());
        throughputController2.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThroughputControllerGui.class.getName());

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroup1HashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup1);
        threadGroup1HashTree.add(sampler1);
        HashTree threadGroup2HashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup2);
        threadGroup2HashTree.add(throughputController1, sampler2);
        threadGroup2HashTree.add(throughputController2, sampler3);
        threadGroup2HashTree.add(throughputController2, sampler4);

        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/example.jmx"));
    }
}
```

Produces JMeter [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) like:

[image: JMeter Test Plan from Java Code]

Which should be something you're looking for.

---

Also be aware that there is a way easier option of creating JMeter Test Plans without using JMeter GUI, [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool provides possibility to create and run JMeter tests using simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) syntax, check out [Taurus: A New Star in the Test Automation Tools Constellation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) article for more details.

Comment: What if there are bean shell processors, headers , result collectors under the sampler ?
What if I want a test plan tree as in the question ( I edited the test plan tree)

Comment: I have been trying in the same way as you have given, but when i add the bean shell processors and headers, the tree structure is varying a lot.

Comment: And also if I run my code in another computer, the test plan is changing.
Is there a way to lock the test plan structure so as it wont change. ?
I have been working on this from 2 weeks. If you could please help